Rate of Reaction - is it for convenience?
I am a high schooler, i had this doubt while studying chemical kinetics, consider this reaction(elementary) 2A --> B, now let rate of disapperance of A be 4 mol/Ls so now logically since change in concentration of A is twice that of B the rate of B is 2 mol/Ls, now Rate of this reaction is given as 2 mol/Ls (from the formula 1/coeff*d[A]dt) what does the rate of this reaction{2 mol/Ls} mean ? what does it signify, is it just defined for convenince (ie, by knowing this value and the coeffecients we an calculate the rate of all the elements invloved in the reaction.) i understand that rate of reaction tells us the rate at which products are formed and reactants are consumed, but here the rate of disappearance is 4 mol/Ls whereas the rate of reaction is 2 mol/Ls, the are not equal.So what does the rate of a reaction tell us ?, what does it measure ? I am confused. Please help.

What is your question, really? Yes, the rates of appearance of B and disappearance of A are linked to the overall reaction rate via the coefficients, just like you said. And yes, this is pretty convenient. Also yes, 4 is not equal to 2.

-4 is not equal to 2 either.

well i understand rate of disappearance of reactants and rate of formation of product are not same due to stochiometry, my question was "rate of reaction tells us how FAST reactants are consumed and products are formed" but here the are not equal(multiple values). I later figured out my confusion, the statement "how fast the reactants are consumed" here means, the rate at which 2 moles of A are disappearing is equal to the rate at which 1 mole of B is being formed this is how the reaction proceeds so in a way it tells us the rate, is my thinking correct ?

now that i think about it it makes sense, 1 mole of reactant = 2 moles of A, reactant = 2A,rate of disappearance of reactant, i understand now ...

i think i should have be more clearer on the question, i have edited it now, Ivan Neretin

I had this doubt due to lack of clarity, The answer is simple. 'Rate of formation is indeed equal to rate of disappearance', consider this
2 moles A reacts with 5 moles B, i initially thought that what the statement meant was rate of disappearance of 1 mole of A = to the formation of 1 mole of B, Then i realised that what the statement means :
Rate of disappearance of reactants [2 moles of A] = Rate of appearance of products [5 moles of B]. It makes sense now

Most of quantities in science are not necessary, but it is very convenient to have them. They often simplify expressions or pointing out specific properties or states.

The purpose of defining reaction rates is obvious, avoiding any ambiguity when relying on reaction/product rates.
Additionally, they are advantage if evaluating linked reactions. For an illustrative  reaction chain
$$\ce{3 A ->[-X] 2 B ->[+ 2 Y] 3 C ->[-Z]D},$$
concentrations of B and C are in the constant, steady state if reaction rates of all three reactions are the same.

Formally, you can consider this approach:
For reaction $\ce{2 A -> 3 B}$, reaction of 2 molecules of $\ce{A}$,  forming 3 molecules of $\ce{B}$ can be considered as 1 formal reaction operation.
When we multiply everything by the Avogadro constant $N_\text{A} \approx \pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$ then $\pu{2 mol A}$ form $\pu{3 mol B}$ during the formal $\pu{1 mol}$ of reaction operations.
Applying time derivative, we get respective absolute reactant, product and reaction rates in $\pu{mol s-1}$, or we can go for the respective concentration variants, e.g. in $\pu{mol L-1 s-1}$.
Similar approach is valid for expression of the standard reaction enthalpy (or other state functions), based on respective standard  enthalpies  (or respective state function values )  of formation of reactants and products.

I figured it out, thanks for your answer though

Sure. An alternative angle does not make any harm.

The rate of the given reaction is $4$ mol A per liter and per second. It is also $2$ mol B per liter and per second. If you do not want to give the rate of reaction with reference to a given product, you must choose the rate of reaction of the product appearing with the coefficient $1$ in the chemical equation (here B). If there is no such substance in the chemical equation, you must choose the rate of reaction of any other reagent, and divide it by the corresponding coefficient (here $2$ for A). As a consequence, the rate $r$ of the reaction $2$A -> B is :
$r$ = - $d$[B]/$dt$ = - ($1/2$) $d$[A]/$dt$

we get a value in the end right ?(by dividing the coeff), this value is the rate of the reaction, so what does it tell us was my question, and i figured it out...

thanks for the help
